# How to export/import a type when using CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, requirejs

**TypeScript + RequireJS** exports are not working together... I'm probably doing something wrong, btw eventually I can't get what exactly is...

The error is: 
`'TStartReturn' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

P.S.
I'm unable to use ESM modules. Only CommonJS.

***Example:***

```
// ../interfaces.ts
  type TIndex = number
  type TStartReturn = void

  module.exports = {
    TIndex,
    TStartReturn,
    // error 'TStartReturn' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
    ...
  }


// index.ts
  const { TStartReturn } = require('../interfaces/index.ts')
  // error const start = (): TImageParserReturn => {
  // SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

  const start = (): TStartReturn => {
   ...
  }
```

[image: rn]

Comment: just try using `export type ....`

Comment: @DanielA.White hi! Thanks, btw how should I import it in the other file? Now I get the same problem where I importing the above types.

Comment: @kai it's a ESM syntax. It won't work inside CommonJS ecosystem...

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll just remove my comment to avoid misleading anyone else.